# Filtering out rows for a specific factor level over a specified date range in R

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

Assume you have the following dataframe `df`

```
code  date             value
<fct>  <date>           <dbl>
01    2000-01-01          23
01    2005-01-01         435 
01    2010-01-01        1000
01    2015-01-01          65
02    2000-01-01          02
02    2005-01-01       50000
02    2010-01-01        3243
02    2015-01-01        6473
```

Let's say you want to filter out values from certain factor levels based on a specific date range, while keeping everything else.

For example, `if` code == "01" `when` date <= "2010-01-01" and `if` code == "02" `when` date > "2010-01-01", `then` filter those rows out, `else` return the data as normal. So, the result would look like this:

```
code  date             value
<fct>  <date>           <dbl>
01    2015-01-01          65
02    2000-01-01          02
02    2005-01-01       50000
02    2010-01-01        3243
```

I know you can accomplish this by splitting the data frame by the factor levels you care about and then using `rbind()` to bring the filtered data together.

```
df_1 <-
 df |>
 filter(
 code == "01",
 date > "2010-01-01"
)

df_2 <-
 df |>
 filter(
 code == "02",
 date <= "2010-01-01"
)

df_3 <-
rbind(df_1, df_2)
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a smoother way of doing this within a single `filter()` command. I've tried using `ifelse()` and `if` statements and `case_when()`, but couldn't figure out a way to make them account for the second variable (the specific date range). Using conditionals within a `filter()` function is also difficult in this case. I think the tricky part is that what I'm trying to do isn't a simple "if, then, else" operation, but rather an "if, **when**, then, else" chain of operations. I'm not sure if this is too complicated to do within a single `filter()` and the `rbind()` method I've shown is the best of method, or if there's something else. I would appreciate any thoughts you may have on this. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you just want `filter((code == "01" & date > "2010-01-01") | (code == "02" & date <= "2010-01-01"))`.

Comment: @johnny_gillette you should review compound logical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really no need for `if/else`ing, you can do this using logical operators. Since you're using base pipes `|>`, you consider using `base::subset`.

```
> dat |> 
+   subset(!(code == '01' & date <= '2010-01-01') & 
+            !(code == '02' & date > '2010-01-01'))
  code       date value
4   01 2015-01-01    65
5   02 2000-01-01     2
6   02 2005-01-01 50000
7   02 2010-01-01  3243
> dat |> 
+   subset((code == '01' & date > '2010-01-01') | 
+            (code == '02' & date <= '2010-01-01'))
  code       date value
4   01 2015-01-01    65
5   02 2000-01-01     2
6   02 2005-01-01 50000
7   02 2010-01-01  3243
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("01", "02"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(10957, 
12784, 14610, 16436, 10957, 12784, 14610, 16436), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(23, 435, 1000, 65, 2, 50000, 3243, 6473)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(
code = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02"),
date = c("2000-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2015-01-01"),
value = c(23L, 435L, 1000L, 65L, 2L, 50000L, 3243L, 6473L),
data = structure(c(10957, 12784, 14610, 16436, 10957, 12784, 14610, 16436), class = "Date")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df %>%
  filter((code == "01" & date > "2010-01-01") | (code == "02" & date <= "2010-01-01"))
#>   code       date value       data
#> 1   01 2015-01-01    65 2015-01-01
#> 2   02 2000-01-01     2 2000-01-01
#> 3   02 2005-01-01 50000 2005-01-01
#> 4   02 2010-01-01  3243 2010-01-01
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the data without any operators except `[`:

```
df[!(
  (df$code == "01" & df$date <= "2010-01-01") |
    (df$code == "02" & df$date > "2010-01-01")
  ), ]
```

This with data from @jared_mamrot results into:

```
  code       date value       data
4   01 2015-01-01    65 2015-01-01
5   02 2000-01-01     2 2000-01-01
6   02 2005-01-01 50000 2005-01-01
7   02 2010-01-01  3243 2010-01-01
```